# Remove <li> elements based on data attrribute on child

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<li><div class="abc"><a href="https://www.google.com" data-test="male">John</a></div></li>
<li><div class="abc"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" data-test="female">Maria</a></div></li>
<li><div class="abc"><a href="https://www.instagram" data-test="male">Peter</a></div></li>
```

What I'm trying to do is to completely remove/hide the two `<li>` that have `data-test="male"` value, without jquery. Any help/suggestion would help.

Comment: Your problem can be split into several subproblems: 1. Find `a` with `data-test=male`. 2. For every `a` in found collection. 3. Find `closest` parent `li`. 4. And remove it. Each of these subproblems has been asked many times on the Internet and StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you Yeldar, Even that step description helps a lot because I'm really new in javascript. I managed to do this in jquery but in plain javascript I'm completely lost.

Comment: Do you use jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the power of CSS selectors:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li a[data-test="male"]'), function(el) {
  el.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
});
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.google.com" data-test="male">John</a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" data-test="female">Maria</a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.instagram" data-test="male">Peter</a></div>
</li>
```

APIs used:

- [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
- [ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Answer (score 0):

if you targets browser is all support `querySelector`. You can use

```
{parentDom}.querySelector('a[data-test="male"]').parentNode.parentNode
```

to find the `li` you need.

The documents related:

1. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)

Comment: That will only find the first one. Anyway, after I find it, how do I remove/hide it?

Comment: I'm less consider about your question. and the @Siah 's answer is more correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**Element.closest**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element (or the current element itself) which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it
>   returns null.

Since this is still experimental make sure to check browser support [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest) and the polyfill provided below in this answer.

How to use:

```
var el = element.closest(<[css selector]>);
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```js
(function() {
  var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test=male]'),
    i = 0,
    len = selectors.length;

  for (i, len; i < len; i++) {
    var current = selectors[i];
    current.closest('li').remove();
  }
})();
```

```html
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.google.com" data-test="male">John</a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" data-test="female">Maria</a></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="abc"><a href="https://www.instagram" data-test="male">Peter</a></div>
</li>
```

---

For browsers that do not support this you can use the following polyfill provided by MDN:

```
if (window.Element && !Element.prototype.closest) {
    Element.prototype.closest = 
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i,
            el = this;
        do {
            i = matches.length;
            while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {};
        } while ((i < 0) && (el = el.parentElement)); 
        return el;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work on old browsers too

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
for (var i=0; i< els.length; i++){
    if (els[i].firstChild.getAttribute('data-test') === 'male') {
        els[i].parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(els[i].parentNode);
    }
}
```